# What is wrong with printing the maximum in awk

Tags: awk

I use this script for printing the maximum of the second column:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=   0}{if ($2>a) a=$2 fi} END{print a}' file
```

file:

```
3830.52482 5.78305
3849.67744 7.10715
3868.92583 7.23076
3888.27046 7.67286
3907.71181 9.21546
3986.45416 11.24000
4006.38643 12.57840
4026.41837 12.39920
4046.55046 12.39390
4066.78321 12.17150
4087.11713 13.03400
4107.55271 12.83100
4128.09047 13.23370
4148.73093 13.40080
4169.47458 13.34160
4190.32196 12.83620
4211.27357 13.02260
4232.32993 12.27750
4253.49158 12.31420
4274.75904 11.57470
4296.13284 9.65358
4317.61350 10.84840
4339.20157 12.88430
4360.89757 13.45180
4382.70206 12.76190
4404.61557 13.58690
4426.63865 14.02720
4448.77184 14.49020
```

The result:

```
bash maximum.sh 
9.96591
```

But there are greater numbers in the second column.
I got this number even the input does not contain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk`  is NOT shell its a different language itself, you did it logically correct only thing syntax `fi` shouldn't be there, try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=0}{if($2>a){a=$2}} END{print a}' Input_file
```

---

---

OR you could simply use conditional operators as follows to set get Maximum value in 2nd field like as follows:

```
awk '{a=$2>a?$2:a} END{print a}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** OP was already going on right track, create a variable and check a condition on each line if current line's 2nd field is GREATER than variable's value then assign variable value to 2nd field else keep it as it is. In `END` section of this program print variable value then.